# Why weren't Kingdom Heart volumes released regularly?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Why did Kingdom Hearts manga series release new volumes so far apart from each other?

The game has been out for a long time, so the plot is pretty much predictable.

Plus, why have they stopped KH2 in the middle, and begin with KH358/2?

Comment: No release is currently planned for Kingdom Hearts II volumes 3, 4, and 5, or for Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days, since Tokyopop having lost the license to the manga. Neither Disney nor Square Enix has had any comment on this.

Comment: Sounds very suspicious... They're the produce. After all

Comment: You can't publish without a publisher or a license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, the publications of English volumes weren't that far apart; the English *Kingdom Hearts* and *Chain of Memories* were on a release cycle around 90 days.

[image]

However, that changed in 2008, when TOKYOPOP, the English publisher, underwent a major corporate restructuring. Many of their projects, including *Kingdom Hearts* translations, were delayed following the first *Kingdom Hearts II* release. This effectively slowed the English releases of *Kingdom Hearts II* to a halt.

In addition, Shiro Amano (the artist) went on hiatus from *Kingdom Hearts II* after volume 2 in favor of *Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days*, so Japanese versions stopped after volume 2 as well. (I don't believe Amano or the producers had any comment on *why* he did this.)

*Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days* has been completed with 5 volumes, but shortly after Tokyopop's reorganization was finished, they lost the majority of their licenses and effectively shut down, which halted the English *Kingdom Hearts* series. Thus, those English volumes never saw the light of day.

On a side note: Recently, [Yen Press announced that they had purchased the rights to the *Kingdom Hearts* series](http://geek-news.mtv.com/2013/04/02/sakuracon-hatsune-miku-kingdom-hearts/). They will be [re-releasing some of the old volumes](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_series_(manga)#Licensing_Issues) first, then:

> Yen will kick things off with the first volume of the fourth series, "Kingdom Hearts 365/2*[sic]* days" in November, and it will release the four-volume "Kingdom Hearts" series as two omnibus volumes (dubbed "Kingdom Hearts Final Mix") in May 2013 and the two-volume "Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories" as a single omnibus in June 2014.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days Vol. 5 cover]